# Tensorflow Windows 10 install

Tags: tensorflow

I am  trying to install tensorflow on win10 through pip. What should I do with this error: ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_6.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable.

I have installed cuDNN and also enviromental path is set by nvidia manual.

Answer (score 0):

Download cuDNN v6.0 => https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn it has the .dll file you need in the bin folder and add the 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin' subdirectory for Windows to find the DLL in system variables.

v8.0 can be any version of cuDNN you already have installed.